# iOS LayoutKit mutable layouts

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, mutable

I've been recently playing with [LayoutKit](http://layoutkit.org) and while the framework is clean and reasonably powerful, I'm struggling with finding the right pattern to implement mutable UI components (such as a label that tracks a live LIKE count on a user comment). Here are my two questions, that really boil down to the same fundamental principle - how can I update the UI generated by LayoutKit?

Specifically...

## Scenario 1:

What's the recommended way to get my hands on the `UIView` instances generated by an instantiated `Layout`?

In the "Hello World" example [listed on the site](http://layoutkit.org/#hello-world), say I want to change the image displayed by the `UIImage`. The only way I can think of doing it is by keeping a reference to it from the `config` closure thusly (<<<<< == my edits):

```
var myImageView: UIImageView? = nil   // <<<<<

let image = SizeLayout<UIImageView>(width: 50, height: 50, config: { imageView in
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "earth.jpg")

    myImageView = imageView           // <<<<<
})

let label = LabelLayout(text: "Hello World!", alignment: .center)

let stack = StackLayout(
    axis: .horizontal,
    spacing: 4,
    sublayouts: [image, label])

let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 8)
let helloWorld = InsetLayout(insets: insets, sublayout: stack)
helloWorld.arrangement().makeViews(in: rootView)

myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "someOtherImage.jpg")   // <<<<<
```

However, this approach presents challenges in some scenarios and is generally klunky. What am I missing?

## Scenario 2:

Say that I want to change the label embedded deep in some layout from saying "something short" to "something very very long that requires a recalculation of the layout".

Two approaches to this problem I can think of:

1. Recreate the layout with the updated information and recreate the whole UI tree. That, however, seems like a crazy expensive operation just to update the text of a label.
2. Recreate the layout using appropriate `viewReuseId`s and go the animation route, but instead apply the changes instantly:

.

```
// Apply the initial layout.
before.arrangement(width: 350, height: 250).makeViews(in: rootView)

// Prepare the animation to the final layout.
after.arrangement(width: 350, height: 250).prepareAnimation(for: rootView, direction: .rightToLeft).apply()
```

That also seems like a crazy expensive way of just changing a label value. Again, what am I missing? Can LayoutKit only be used for immutable interfaces?